# MATLAB: Averaging time-series data without loops?

Tags: matlab, time-series, average

I have measured a handful of variables in 30 minute intervals. Time stamps are available in `datevec` or `datenum` format. I want to calculate ...

a) ... daily averages and
b) ... average values at time `x`, e.g. temperature at 11:30, temperature at 12:00, etc. averaged over my whole dataset.

While this is, more or less, easily done with loops, I wonder if there is an easier / more convenient way to work with time-series, since this is a quite basic task after all?

/edit 1: As per request: [click me for sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9437411/sampledata_ts.mat)

Comment: I can provide a solution with `accumarray()` if you post some example data.

Comment: I hope 100 measurements are enough: [click me for sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9437411/sampledata_ts.mat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that `datevec()` output is stored in `tvec` and data in `x`, group with `unique(...,'rows')` and accumulate with `accumarray()`:

```
% Group by day
[unDates, ~, subs] = unique(tvec(:,1:3),'rows');

% Accumulate by day
[unDates accumarray(subs, x, [], @mean)]

% Similarly by hour
[unHours, ~, subs] = unique(tvec(:,4:5),'rows');
[unHours accumarray(subs, x, [], @mean)]
```

Comment: +1: any valid solution with `accumarray` deserves it! That baby should be promoted as much as possible :)